# how to automatically discover proxy servers with cocoa api on mac

Tags: macos, proxy

On mac proxy setting, we can select `Auto Proxy Discovery` to automatically discover proxy servers, also we can use `kSCPropNetProxiesProxyAutoDiscoveryEnable` to fetch value of enabled, while what I really need is that how to get the proxy server we use with this setting.

Any idea will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

just get config with `kSCPropNetProxiesProxyAutoConfigURLString`